# Need help figure out how to use python regexp search return value in dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I'm new to python. Trying to use dictionaries. I am using following code.

```
t_p = dict()

for line in f.readlines():
  stObj = re.search( r'Startpoint:\s(\w+)', line, re.M|re.I)
  enObj = re.search( r'Startpoint:\s(\w+)', line, re.M|re.I)
  slObj = re.search( r'\s*slack\s\(\w+\)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)', line, re.M|re.I)
  if slObj:
    sla = slObj.group(3)
  if enObj:
    endpoint = enObj.group(1)
    t_p[ep] = { 'sla' : sla }

f.close()
```

I keep getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "play.py", line 15, in <module>
    t_p[ep] = { 'sla' : sla } 
NameError: name 'sla' is not defined
```

I don't get why it thinks 'sla' is not defined.

Comment: Because the body of `if slObj` is not being executed.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `sla` is inside an `if`:

```
if slObj:
    sla = slObj.group(3)
```

This is not getting executed. `slObj` is `None`, instead of a `MatchObject`. Your regex is not working.